# xpath text after strong element with following-sibling does not work

Tags: php, html, xpath, simplexml, siblings

I checked and in many examples

```
following-sibling::text()[1]
```

is given as a correct answer to receive text after a strong-tag. I marked the text I'm interested in with asterisks:

```
    <?php
    $html='
      <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>    
            <div class="someclass">
                <h2 class="h3">header 1</h2>
                <ul class="bulleted">
                    <li><strong>prop1: </strong>**name**</li>
                    <li><strong>prop2: </strong>**street**</li>
                    <li><strong>prop is 3: </strong>**city**</li>
                    <li><strong>prop 4: </strong>**more**</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
    $doc->loadHtml($html);
    $data = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
    $properties = $data->xpath('//strong/following-sibling::text()[1]');

    var_dump($properties);
```

What I always get is the content of the [strong], but not the text within the [li] [/li] without the content of [strong]:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#3 (1) {
    public $strong =>
    string(7) "prop1: "
  }
  [1] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#4 (1) {
    public $strong =>
    string(7) "prop2: "
  }
  [2] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#5 (1) {
    public $strong =>
    string(11) "prop is 3: "
  }
  [3] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#6 (1) {
    public $strong =>
    string(8) "prop 4: "
  }
}
```

I would be glad if you point me to the error I do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use SimpleXML for this XPath operation, it is limited in some ways, in your case the limitation is that you can not return text nodes with SimpleXML Xpath. [DOMXPath](http://php.net/class.domxpath) is much more capable, it can return all node-types including text-nodes:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$properties = $xpath->query('//strong/following-sibling::text()[1]');

foreach ($properties as $property)
  var_dump($property->textContent);
```

Result:

```
string(8) "**name**"
string(10) "**street**"
string(8) "**city**"
string(8) "**more**"
```